# Attachment Meta Data Not Saving When Using Radio Buttons

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created the following meta data options for my image attachments. Basically, the user selects a radio button - the appropriate class is then added to a div, which is wrapped around the attachment. For some reason, the selected radio button value isn't being saved. However, I have noticed that if I switch the input to be a regular text field, everything works perfectly fine.

```
function add_attachment_classes_field( $form_fields, $post ) {
$field_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'classes', true );
  $form_fields['classes'] = array(
    'value' => $field_value ? $field_value : '',
    'label' => __( 'Classes' ),
    'input' => 'html',
    'html' => "<div><input checked='checked' style='width: initial' type='radio' name='border-style' value=''> None</div>
                <div><input style='width: initial' type='radio' name='border-style' value='green-border'> Green</div>
                <div><input style='width: initial' type='radio' name='border-style' value='red-border'> Red</div>
                <div><input style='width: initial' type='radio' name='border-style' value='jagged-border'> Jagged</div>
                <div><input style='width: initial' type='radio' name='border-style' value='purple-border'> Purple</div>",
  );  
 return $form_fields;
}

function save_attachment_classes( $attachment_id ) {
  if ( isset( $_REQUEST['attachments'][$attachment_id]['classes'] ) ) {
    $classes = $_REQUEST['attachments'][$attachment_id]['classes'];
    update_post_meta( $attachment_id, 'classes', $classes );
  }
}

function wrap_my_div($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt) {
    $field_value = get_post_meta( $id, 'classes', true );
    return '<div class="'.$field_value.'">'.$html.'</div>';
}
add_action( 'edit_attachment', 'save_attachment_classes' );
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'add_attachment_classes_field', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'wrap_my_div', 10, 8 );
```

Comment: Your first radio button element is always going to be checked. Even if you select another value and save it when you reload the page it's going to show the first. Take a look at the `checked()` function. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with the name attribute for the radio button.

I changed each one to the following and it solved the problem:

```
name='attachments[{$post->ID}][classes]'
```